# Заставить программу ждать выполнение метода, прежде чем перейти к следующему

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня есть метод, в котором я вызываю несколько других методов. Так как выполняются они долго, я хочу в начале их выполнения вывести в новом окне табличку "Подождите! Графики выполняются". Вот мой код.

Проблема состоит в том, что запуске программы, табличка появляется, но не заполняется данными и выглядит как на картинке. А нормально она выглядит уже в конце выполнения программы.

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design3.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButtonConfirm.clicked.connect(self.printGraph)
        self.istart = (self.calendarWidget_1.selectedDate()).toPyDate()
        self.iend = (self.calendarWidget_2.selectedDate()).toPyDate()
        self.istart = self.calendarWidget_1.selectedDate()
        self.iend = self.calendarWidget_2.selectedDate()
        self.WindowDownload = QMessageBox()


    def printGraph(self):
        self.city = self.getCity()
        Graph = getGraph(self.city, self.istart, self.iend)
        self.showMesaggeS()
        self.getFirst(Graph)
        self.getSecond(Graph)
        self.getThird(Graph)
        self.getFourth(Graph)

    def showMesaggeS(self):
        self.WindowDownload.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        self.WindowDownload.setWindowTitle("Повідомлення!")
        self.WindowDownload.setText("Зачекайте! Графіки будуються")
        self.WindowDownload.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.WindowDownload.show()
```

Весь код не прикрепляю, так как там много файлов. Если нужно, могу отдельно загрузить (для справки, там несколько файлов `.py` и файл `.xlsx` из которого я беру данные).

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] . Единственное, что понятно сразу - тяжелые задачи выполняются в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Выполнение расчетов и чтение файлов выносится в тред, обновление интерфейса через сигнал и будет счастье